# Format code spaces to standard (desired) style

Tags: javascript, code-beautification

I am touching an old JavaScript project to add new features. The existing codebase is written like #1 and #2. I like it to be like #3.

codebase #1  `function x (a,b){ c(d('fff')).run('ggg'); }`

codebase #2 `function x(a,b) { c( d('fff')).run('ggg');}`

codebase #3 `function x (a,b) { c( d( 'fff' )).run( 'ggg' );}`

Is there a tool to format the existing codebase to be like #3? If there is not, I'd like to write this tool, is it worth doing? Or there's a better way of dealing with this?

Comment: Seriously, please avoid copy/pasting posts across the network, it's rude to the websites. Tailor your posts to each specific website. Your question fails the [second point here](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as you don't provide a clear list of requirements.

Comment: Literal copy-paste from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37916466/code-space-formatter) deleted SO question. fireflies, you were asked to: _"make sure to read their help center carefully and to avoid just copy/pasting your question there, instead tailoring it to this specific site."_